# Is it wrong to say "How many are we?"

Tags: pronouns, british-english, determiners

So I'm in class one day and I try to initiate a headcount of everyone in my class and so I decide to ask openly and say "How many are we?". But to my absolute shock I had some other person (along with a couple others more) telling me the question didn't make sense (grammatically) because I should've said "How many people are in the class/ take this class ?" I chose not to debate on the subject because I thought it was an American English thingy (like every thingy) but I still need to clear it up because I feel I was without error.

Comment: *many* is a determiner and pronouns do not normally take a determiner. It's unidiomatic to say *the he, *my he, *a we.

Comment: Rewording a sentence doesn't make the original grammatically wrong. You should ask them what specifically is wrong with it. I may not be commonly used, but it's grammar is fine.

Comment: *How  many are we?* is grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

> How many are we?

would not be a common way to say what you were trying to say, and sounds weird. I think you were trying to say something along the lines of

> How many of us are there?

which is still shorter than your classmate's suggestions but sounds better.

I can't quite put my finger on why `How many are we?` sounds wrong, but it definitely does.

Comment: I think it's grammatically correct, but I agree that it sounds unusual. I think it sounds unusual for two reasons: (1) It sounds kind of formal or literary, which is out of place in a classroom context, and (2) it could sound like a partial sentence. The listener might expect to hear something like "how many are we [going to see]?", for instance, but the sentence just suddenly stops short.